# ISERROR with multiple if condition

Tags: excel, error-handling, excel-formula, conditional-statements

I want to put Y if cell A1 is negative OR an error. I want to put N otherwise. But this formula is not working:

```
if(OR(ISERROR(A1),A1<0),"Y","N")
```

Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Excel evaluates both parts of an `OR` expression independent if the first part is true. So `A1<0` and therefore the `OR` function result in an error if `A1` contains an error.

You can try something like that:

```
IF(ISERROR(A1),"Y",IF(A1<0,"Y","N"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The newer¹ [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) can shorten your multiple boolean criteria by providing a default response when an error is encountered.

```
=IF(IFERROR(A1<0, TRUE), "Y", "N")
```

Attempting to resolve `A1<0` when A1 is any error (e.g. `#DIV/0!`, `#N/A`, etc) will result in an error and TRUE will be returned to the IF. When A1 is not an error, `A1<0` is resolved to a boolean result.

[image: a1lessthanerror]

---

¹ <sub>The [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) was introduced with Excel 2007. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>